# How can I find last row in multiple group by WITHOUT window functions over?

Tags: sql-server, group-by, aggregate-functions, row-number

I have a query that returns a result fairly quickly:

```
SELECT [Date],[AccountCode],[ModelCode],[Generic],SUM([MTMusd]) AS 'MTMusd'
FROM [dbo].[MTM]
WHERE [AccountCode] = 'XXX'
AND [ModelCode] = '1'
GROUP BY [Date],[AccountCode],[ModelCode],[Generic]
ORDER BY [Date]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MTM](
    [AccountCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [ModelCode] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [Date] [date] NULL,
    [TIMESTAMP] [time](7) NOT NULL,
    [Generic] [nvarchar](50) NULL,
    [MTMUsd] [float] NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

However, I don't want `SUM()` I want `LAST()`.

In the GROUP BY I have missed out `[TIMESTAMP]` which is the time of day. I want my query to return the record with the LAST `TIMESTAMP` for each GROUP { `[Date],[AccountCode],[ModelCode],[Generic]` }

How can I achieve this efficiently? I have approx 5 millions rows.

I tried `ROW_NUMBER() OVER ()` based example I found, but processing took an order of minutes.

Comment: I don't want MAX(TIMESTAMP) I want MTMusd for the LAST(TIMESTAMP)

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` is one standard way to do it. Read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6841605/get-top-1-row-of-each-group and http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/86415/retrieving-n-rows-per-group for comparison of different methods and ideas how to make the query fast (you'll need proper index).

Comment: This question looks slightly more complex than many, and the answer would probably include consideration of indexing. Might be better to post at dba.stackexchange.com?

Comment: For starters, an index on `AccountCode, ModelCode` would help filtering out the rows before they're even grouped (assuming you need far less than all 5 million rows).

Comment: Looks like the table has no clustered index (?) Is it possible to create one? Even an non-clustered index on `AccountCode, ModelCode` might result in a substantial number of RID lookups and if you tried to make it a covering index for this query then you have almost duplicated the table. But if you could cluster the table by `AccountCode, ModelCode, Date, Timestamp` maybe the performance problem starts to go away without abandoning `Row_Number()`

Comment: Odd that SUM is very fast even with no clever indexing/clustering. Pity TOP could not be used in someway.